# How to create two separate sites login/registration with single database users table

Tags: laravel, cakephp

I have two different websites one in Cakephp 2.6 Framework and another in Laravel 8x Framework.
I have two different databases but i want to uses my Cakephp site's database users table for login/registration for both sites, how to integrate this solution in my frameworks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding: It doesn't related to frameworks, instead it is a matter of business logic and can be handled with two steps.

step 1 => Add a "system_code/website_code" column in the users table.
step 2 => Add additional check for system_code along with login credentials in your code base of both websites.